# Why is this array not found

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know why this array is not found
I'm trying to find a number that correspinds, but this doesn't work for some reason

```
public static int sortLevel(char level) 
{ 
    final char[] LEVEL = {'7', '1', '9', '8'};
    for (int index = 0; index < LEVEL.length; index++) 
    {
        if(LEVEL(index) == level) return index;
    }

    // error code for not found, should not be reached
    return -1;
}
```

it returns error

cannot find symbol -- method LEVEL(int)

okay,dat works, but I have another problem

So, I have a Course Class, and I don't know what this method accepts as a parameter, 
Any ideas as to how,

this is the name of the method

```
public int compareTo(Course otherCourse)
```

this is the method call

```
course1.compareTo()
```

what do I put inside the brackets

Comment: You index an array with `[]`.  You call a method with `()`.  There is no method named `LEVEL`.

Comment: (You should learn how to figure this out yourself.  It complains about "LEVEL(int)".  Where does something that looks like that appear?  As what you think is an array.  But the compiler says "method" -- why is that?  Why does the compiler think "LEVEL" is a method (even if a not-found one)?  Then maybe it "clicks" that you didn't do the array indexing properly.)  **Net:  Read the messages and reread them, and see if you can maybe figure out what they're saying.**

Comment: You put another Course. So something like course1.compareTo(course2);

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are wrong.

```
if(LEVEL(index) ...
```

should be

```
if(LEVEL[index]...
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect:

```
(LEVEL(index) == level)
```

Parenthesis are use to call methods (eg `System.out.println()`).

To access an array in Java, you use square brackets:

```
(LEVEL[index] == level)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change it to

```
if(LEVEL[index] == level) return index;
```